# Check that String is alphanumeric with length 1 to 5

Tags: java, regex, string, alphanumeric

I have wrote the following test code snippet:

```
"123".matches("\\[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}");
```

However, it returns `false`.

Why and how to fix this?

Comment: I'm surprised it runs at all, given the imbalanced `[]`.

Comment: The first `[` should not be escaped. Remove the ``\``.

Comment: @Andy Turne lenght should be {1,5}

Comment: @Andy Turne You are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're escaping the first square bracket with the `\\`, which means the expression between the square brackets isn't treated as a character class. Remove the escaping and you should be OK:

```
"123".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}"
// Here -------^
```

Answer (score 7):

By escaping  the first `[`, you made it a literal `[`, while you wanted to define a *character class* (bracket expression).

Remove `\`:

```
"123".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}");
               ^
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/LRHneU):

```
System.out.println("123".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}")); // = > true
```

Answer (score 4):

Regex without `\\` will work. You don't need to escape anything.

```
"123".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}");
```